# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkbox, uibutton

I am making an app in which I am using tableview and in each table cell I am using checkboxes. Now I am stuck in this place that when checkbox is checked I want to get value of that table-cell. I am showing messages id in table cell I want to get `messages_Id` of that cells whose checkboxes are checked. Means if I select 1 checkbox its message id is store in `NSString` and if I select 2 checkboxes then 2 messages of these checkboxes are store in string how it can be done. I had maked array in which I want to store checkboxes messages id but I am getting following exception. Below is my sample code of check boxes action

```
-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.activitiesTableView_];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.activitiesTableView_ indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])               {
        [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.checkboxmessageArray removeObject:[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]objectForKey:@"messageid"]];//here i am removing whien chekbox is unchecked
    else {
        [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.checkboxmessageArray addObject:[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]objectForKey:@"messageid"]];// i am getting exception in this line
    }
}
```

What is the reason why I am getting this exception stuck in it for many days?

Comment: you can assign tag value of checkbox button.index value is tag value of checkbox.best and easy way for work.

Comment: how it can be done ??? will u provide some stuff for it ?

Comment: @MishalAwan you have only one checkbox at each cell?

Comment: yeah one checkbox cell

Comment: @MishalAwan so you want functionality like when you tap on button then message_id for that index will be save into array and on another tap it will remove from array. right?

Comment: @Mishal, Please attach your crash Log in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the one common `NSMutableArray` in `ViewDidLoad` just like

```
self.checkboxmessageArray =[NSMutableArray New];



-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblvie];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblvie indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

        if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
            [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [self.checkboxmessageArray removeObject:[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]objectForKey:@"messageid"]];


        }


        else {
            [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            messageid.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]objectForKey:@"messageid"];
            [self.checkboxmessageArray addObject:[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]objectForKey:@"messageid"]];//assume that this is your message ID array,  here u convert the string



                            }
                            [self.tblvie reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

if u want to sent the **messageID** to server, follow this and customize yourself

```
 NSString *finalIDStr;

if (self.checkboxmessageArray .count==0)
{
    finalIDStr=@"";
}
else
{


    NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: self.checkboxmessageArray options:kNilOptions error:nil];
   finalIDStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the final ID Str==%@",finalIDStr);

}
```

**finally** pass this **yourmessageidStr** string to server

the `Console` output just like

```
  the final ID Str=["658681","655917","655904"]
```

Answer (score 0):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method assign button tag value to indexPath value like

```
checkbox.tag=indexPath.row
```

and get value from

```
-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [self.checkimageArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    ///additional code

}
```

Comment: due to this selecteed checkboxes are store in tht array ?

Comment: basely this is depend on your need.there are so many way for this.
you used sender.selected property for this.